# How to take notes with keyboard input and drawings?

Tags: notes, drawing

I have a tablet I'm expecting to take a lot of notes with. Is there a way I can type with the keyboard and draw with the touch screen?

I've tried Evernote, which can type with the keyboard, and Freenote, which can draw with the screen but can one app toggle between both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Xperia Notes App](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7za7z7gzed5qqki/SemcNotes.apk). This allows you to add texts, draw pictures and record audios as well. It also has a [widget](http://www.mediafire.com/download/o5a8l0728ay1svo/NoteWidget.apk).

<sup>But the app may not be compatible with your device.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. What is the widget called? I can't find it in the list of widgets when adding.

Comment: What is this called? I can't find an app named Xperia Note in the store.

Comment: This is a native app that comes with Xperia devices. So this *may not be* available in the play store and *may not be* compatible with your device as well. The app is listed as **Notes**

Comment: Ok thanks it works. But if I have any questions about it I can't search for the answers. Is there a way to have the page display horizontally? I run out of room when drawing things by hand.

Comment: No. You can't @Celeritas 
All you can do is to use it vertically.

Comment: Please **do not** use URL shorteners here.